# ERROR: for app no such device

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    container_name: myapp
    volumes:
      #- "../app:/root/www/myapp:rw"
      - myapp:/root/www/myapp:rw

volumes:
  myapp:
    #driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: uid=500,gid=500
      device: ../app
```

I try to share my host folder to the guest container with a named volume. I've got the following error message?

```
ERROR: for app  no such device
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

What went wrong?

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but bind mounts unfortunately do not support uid & gid anyways... Sorry, you're stuck with the host IDs or the current ID weirdness (if you're on OS X).

Comment: What if I: 1.) Bind mount a host directory to a persistent container. 2.) Inside this container, this folder will be symlinked to another with `ln -s` command. 3.) This symlinked folder will have a named volume shared between this persistent and `app` container and now I can define `uid` for this named volume?

Comment: Tried it, didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need `driver_opts` here. It is for network option.

I think you should try:

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    container_name: myapp
    volumes:
      - "myapp:/root/www/myapp"

volumes:
  myapp:
```

Comment: There are `driver_opts` for both volume and network in docker-compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/driver-opts and https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/driver-opts-1 Also there is a `$ docker volume create --opt` flag (which is used by docker-compose): https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#/driver-specific-options It would be pretty neat to define uid (and maybe gid) as the document suggest, but for now it would be enough if the host volume share would work.

Comment: My Docker version is 1.11.2. The command line document is for 1.12. Maybe that's the case? Edit: Nope, according to this document, it should be supported in 1.11 also: https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

Comment: Your solution making it possible to define a volume from the host? I tried yours, giving me this error message: `ERROR: In file '/docker-compose.yml', volume 'myapp' must be a mapping not a string.`

Comment: I changed  `myapp:/root/www/myapp` to ` "myapp:/root/www/myapp"`